# Recurring Payment for Hosted Solution Payflow Edition

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

In the Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution Integration Guide (Payflow Edition) for UK document there are some errors described. One of the errors are:
31 'Error in adding the recurring profile'

But it this document does not state how can I add a recurring profile using the hosted solution. This is what I am looking for.

Thank you.

**EDIT**:

What I found interesting is that the other guide (non-PayFlow Edition) it says recurring payments are not supported by PayPal Pro Hosted Solution, but in this one there is no information about recurring payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PayPal Payflow page it says that is available in US, CAN, AUS, New Zealand, but not in UK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Recurring Payments are not supported in Hosted Sole Solution.
You can use Recurring payments only if you have a PayPal Payments PRO account(which is available in US,UK and CA) else use Recurring Billing in Payflow(available in US,UK,AUS).

Comment: I found one problem, though. In the PayPal Payflow page it says that is available in US, CAN, AUS, New Zealand, but not in UK. Are you sure it is available in the UK.